# An executable compiled in Mac OS cannot run in Ubuntu server?

Tags: ocaml

I have written a one-line OCaml program: `print_string "hello world!\n"` in my Mac OS. Then I compiled it by `ocamlopt -o test test.ml`, the generated `test` works fine.

Then I scp this `test` to my Ubuntu & Nginx server, where OCaml is not installed. I launched `./test`, and got an error: `-bash: ./code: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

So do I have to install OCaml on the server, and compile my program over there? Isn't it possible to compile my program in Mac OS in a certain way such that the executable alone could run in a Ubuntu server?

Comment: Aside from Jeffrey's answer below, you could also cross-compile, build the executable in a Docker container and extract the resulting binary + linked .so files from the container or build in a VM that matches your target host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executable (binary) formats are not portable across systems, no. ocamlopt produces a format that is native to the system on which you do the compilation, and you shouldn't expect it to run on any other system unless it is of identical type.

You can get portability by compiling to bytecodes instead (using ocamlc rather than ocamlopt). Bytecode executables run more slowly, however.

Comment: I compiled `ocamlc -o code code.ml`, and scp `code` to the server. In the server, `./code` returns `-bash: ./code: /Users/softtimur/.opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlrun: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Your bytecode interpreter (ocamlrun) needs to be in the same place on both systems, or you can run bytecodes with "ocamlrun code".

Comment: So i still need to install `ocamlrun` in the server? Should I just install `ocamlrun` or the entire `OCaml` in the server?

Comment: You will need ocamlrun and libraries on the server. So you might as well install all of OCaml.